# Access Laravel website with valet in local network

Tags: laravel, nginx, local-network, valet

I want to access the website using another device in the same network.

I don’t want to use `valet share` As it share it publicly.

I have followed the https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/valet#sharing-sites-on-your-local-network and changed the valet.conf with removing the 127.0.0.1 from the line

Still can’t access the my website with 192.168.1.10/application.test (example ip)

What I get is (404 - Not Found) Which I think is from nginx

Please help